# Are delegates a good approach to share variables between two windows?

Tags: c#, wpf, delegates

Are delegates a good approach to share variables between two forms/windows in WPF and C# generally? I know where a lot of ways of passing functions/variables between two windows, and I'd like to know if there are better ways, with less code and headache.

Thank you.

Example:

```
internal delegate void getName(String name);
internal static event getName evtGetUsername;

private void btn1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        evtGetUsername(textBox.Text);
    }
```

In the other form:

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Window2.evtGetUsername += new Window2.getName(Name);
    }

    public void Name(String name)
    {
        lstBox.Items.Add(name);
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean?  How would you share a variable using a delegate?  You usually share state by sharing state.

Comment: @CharlesMager Well, technically sharing a reference to a method is sharing state ;)

Comment: Delegates are a tool, and like all tools, they can be used effectively or ineffectively.  Can someone use delegates effectively to communicate between windows, sure.  Can someone use delegates ineffectively to communicate between windows, also yes.  One can also communicate effectively and ineffectively without using delegates.  Having every person listing out their favorite way of communicating between objects  is way too broad of a question.

Comment: @CharlesMager I added an example

Comment: @Servy thank you for your answer, please look at my edits, I added and example. Is that a good way of dealing with delegates?

Comment: @user2729661 That depends on what you're trying to do.  We can't possibly say whether or not it's a quality implementation without knowing the requirements of the application.  And at the end of the day, do *you* think it's a good implementation?  If you do, and it accomplishes your goals, then go ahead and use it.

Comment: @Servy I want to pass the content of a textbox (second form) to a listbox in my main form.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

¿What about using a common static class?

```
public static class Session { 
    public static String Name { get; set; }
}

//Window1
public Window1() {
    Session.Name = "Window 1 instantiated.";
}

//Window2
public Window2() {
    txtControl.Text = Session.Name;
}
```

That works in most of the cases

Comment: Nice approach, by the way. But I think "static" is not OOP enough.

Comment: You can put it into another file / namespace  / class, i don't see why isn't this "OOP enough", the class Session is a shared object.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would use some form of dependency injection, and use that to effectively share a settings class between two windows.

Essentially, both windows have the same class injected into them, and they can both share the same variables within the settings class.

If you dont want to use dependency injection, use a singleton instead (google this for more info).

I have found that both of these approaches work well. Usually, you can add some wrappers to persist the settings to a file, I would recommend JSON.NET.